# Connecting to created database 11g in sql developer

Tags: oracle11g

I just created database through this tutorial http://www.fehily.com/books/createdb/createdb_oracle_11g_2.html - all works well - I can login via sqlplus.
But how to login on sql developer? I trying to figure out this, but nothing

part of my `[listener.ora][1]`

```
# LISTENER =
#  (ADDRESS_LIST=
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))   

# SID_LIST_<lsnr>
#   List of services the listener knows about and can connect 
#   clients to.  There is no default.  See the Net8 Administrator's
#   Guide for more information.
#
# SID_LIST_LISTENER=
#   (SID_LIST=
#   (SID_DESC=
#           #BEQUEATH CONFIG
#          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=salesdb.mycompany)
#          (SID_NAME=sid1)          
#          (ORACLE_HOME=/private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3)
#           #PRESPAWN CONFIG
#         (PRESPAWN_MAX=20)
#     (PRESPAWN_LIST=
#           (PRESPAWN_DESC=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(POOL_SIZE=2)(TIMEOUT=1))
#         )
#        )
#       )
```

[image]

Comment: By looking at your error it is clear that SID is not orcl . it should be the Oracle Database instance name. Use the appropriate name to make it work.In the tutorial database name is "books". So you should use SID as books if you are using SQL Developer.You can post sqlplus connection url here so that we can help you with SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LISTENER.ORA you posted is useless; every single line is commented (see the hash sign at the beginning of the line?). TNSNAMES.ORA might be more useful; post it.

Did you literally follow that guide? It created a database whose `SID = books`, not `orcl`. Otherwise, you should know which name you gave. That's what SQL Developer is complaining about - you put a SID which is unknown.

Saying that you can connect via SQL*Plus means what? Could you share what you typed? Because, that's info that might help. For example, if I want to connect to user SCOTT on my local Express Edition (XE) database, I use

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@xe
```

If I type - at the operating system command prompt - `TNSPING XE`, I get some useful information. Try to do the same:

```
c:\>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 10-SVI-2018 22:15:40

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\lf\Documents\E_0_library\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lf)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (10 msec)

c:\>
```

Comment: I named my db hotel, so that's why it is hotel not books ;) I changed SID and works! Also command tnsping shows that my db is on 1522 port. Now it all works! Thanks